# Bash cd to a directory by just entering its name

Tags: bash, cd

Is there a way to get bash to cd to a directory by default if I just enter the directory name?

Right now what I get is:

```
~ bemmu$ some_directory/
-bash: some_directory/: is a directory
```

What I want to happen is:

```
~ bemmu$ some_directory/
~/some_directory bemmu$
```

Tried to Google a bit but couldn't find an answer. I'm on "*GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)*".

Comment: I think even if it might be implemented, as the interpreter's response to all or undefined, non-existing commands, It would go against the very rules of syntax, that's why it won't be recommended anyhow.

Comment: Answered e.g. [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4262/change-directory-without-typing-cd) (autocd option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to bottom of your .bashrc file

```
try_cd_on_error()
{
    trap trycd ERR
}
trycd() {
    trap "" ERR
    if cd $BASH_COMMAND 2>/dev/null; then
        pwd
        trap trycd ERR
        return
    fi
    trap trycd ERR
}
```

then start a new bash shell, and enter **try_cd_on_error** to set it up, then enter a directory name.

Answer (score 2):

One of the comments points to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4270/108618).

To enable the feature:

```
shopt -s autocd
```

(You may want to add the above line to your `.bashrc`.)

To disable:

```
shopt -u autocd
```

Comment: Good to know for the future, but now I'm on older bash. Looks like this is introduced in 4.0.